# django template white spaces into strings

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In order to remove white spaces around a variable, in twig engine it is possible to do the following:

```
 <a class="btn-
      {{- buttonsuccess -}}
 ">my button</a>
```

Notice the spaces and line break around the variable `buttonsuccess`.

This gives:

```
 <a class="btn-success">my button</a>
```

Notice that the spaces have been removed.

Is there something similar in the template of `django`?

Comment: Last I checked, Django only had [`{% spaceless %}{% endspaceless %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless) to deal with this, which is a lackluster solution and doesn't always work where you need it. Jinja and other template engines have better solutions. However, you can use them with Django instead of the default templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about twig engine, but if `{{- buttonsuccess -}}` is something pre-defined, in the Django you could do this:

Set a `status` (or whatever) variable in the view:

```
def myview(request):
    ...
    context.update({'status': 'success'})
    ...
```

And use it in template:

```
<a class="btn-{{ status }}>my button</a>"
```

That will give the same:

```
<a class="btn-success">my button</a>
```

**EDIT**

Front-End frameworks such as [Bootstrap](https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.5/docs/css/) provide classes based on status like *success* or *warning*. So you could find usefull this in those cases. See [Bootstrap Contextual classes](https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.5/docs/css/#tables-contextual-classes) as a example.

From docs:

```
<!-- On rows -->
<tr class="active">...</tr>
<tr class="success">...</tr>
<tr class="warning">...</tr>
<tr class="danger">...</tr>
<tr class="info">...</tr>
```

Where you could use:

```
<tr class="{{ status }}">...</tr>
```

Comment: Actually that is quite not what I need, I edited a bit my post, hope it's much clearer

Comment: Oh, you mean add various classes but not in the same line?